# How can I generate a complete histogram with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have a very long list in a `numpy.array`.  I want to generate a histogram for it.  However, Numpy's [built in histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) requires a pre-defined number of bins.  What's the best way to generate a full histogram with one bin for each value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an array of integers and the max value isn't too large you can use numpy.bincount:

```
hist = dict((key,val) for key, val in enumerate(numpy.bincount(data)) if val)
```

Edit:
If you have float data, or data spread over a huge range you can convert it to integers by doing:

```
bins = numpy.unique(data)
bincounts = numpy.bincount(numpy.digitize(data, bins) - 1)
hist = dict(zip(bins, bincounts))
```

Comment: np.bincount(np.digitize(...)) is such a useful pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

A bin for every value sounds a bit strange but wouldn't

```
bins=a.max()-a.min()
```

give a similar result?